# Accessing private variable in VBA give "variable not found"

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am trying to implement a linked list. Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing incorrectly? When I try to compile I get this Compile error: Method or data member not found on Set node.nodeValue = val. If I set the LinkedListNode class member variables to public I get this Compile error: Invalid use of property.

LinkedListNode (class module):

```
Option Explicit

' Declare value as integer type
Private nodeValue As Integer
' Declare NextNode as a LinkedListNode object
Private nextNode As LinkedListNode
```

LinkedList (class module):

```
Option Explicit

' Declare head as a LinkedListNode object
Private head As LinkedListNode

' Add node to linked list
Public Sub AddLinkedListNode(val As Integer)
            ' Create node object
            Dim node As New LinkedListNode
            ' Set node object type & value
            Set node = New LinkedListNode
            Set node.nodeValue = val
            ' Connect node to head
            Set node.nextNode = head
            ' Set new node to head
            Set head = node
End Sub
```

TestLL (module):

```
Public Sub TestLinkedList()

' Declare variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim val As Integer
Dim list As New LinkedList
'Dim node As LinkedListNode

' Set val to 1
val = 1

' Add nodes with value = val
For i = 1 To 6
            list.AddLinkedListNode (1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set` is for object-type assignments.  `nodeValue` is declared as Integer

Comment: In addition to Tims' comment, because you've declared `nodeValue` and `nextNode` as private, they are not accessible outside the `LinkedListNode` class code module.  You'll need some Public Properties or Methods to access them